# startActivity hides current layout and dialog

Tags: android, dialog, while-loop, loading

I have a startActivity which shows an alert dialog until my downloading and parsing of the xml is finished in my async task. then I go to the next startActivity. Problem is even with the wait I have for threads for the startActivity, there is nothing shown on screen. if i comment out the command startActivity I see everything. Why is this? can someone help please?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
    ad.setCancelable(false);   
    ad.setMessage("Loading Events");         
    ad.show();



    if (!isNetworkAvailable()){ 
        ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
        ad.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button  
        ad.setMessage("Not Connected Exiting");  
        ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
                     dialog.dismiss();    
                     finish();
                 }  
        });  
        ad.show();
       }
       downloadXML();     
       events=parseXML();

       ((CATApplication)this.getApplication()).setEvents(events);
       try{
       Thread.sleep(10000);
       Intent intent = new Intent(this,EventsListActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);                  
       }catch(Exception e){}
}
//check for network connection
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

public void onPause(){
    File xmlFile = new File("deletefileonexit");
    xmlFile.delete();
    finish();
    super.onPause();
}

private void downloadXML() {
    String url = "locationofxmlonweb";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}

public Events parseXML(){
    Events newEvents=new Events();
    try{
        while(!(new File("locationofxml").exists())){}
        InputStream in=new FileInputStream("locationofxml");
        newEvents=new ParseEventsXML().parse(in);
    }
    catch (Exception e){} 
    return newEvents;
}
```

}

Comment: Remove this: `Thread.sleep(10000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sleep the UI thread and still expect something to be shown.

Remove this line:

```
 Thread.sleep(10000);
```

What you want is a handler and post a runnable with a wait of 10000 then start your next activity.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

     .....


     new Handler().postDelayed(t, 10000);
    }

    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        };
    };
```

Thats the answer, but it's still fundamentally flawed why you would want to guess a random time and then start the next activity. You should look at using a DialogFragment with an ASyncTask and when it returns then you can start your second activity.

Comment: thank you I moved the delay outside the thread and it was fixed.Basically i am downloading a file . I need to check when its downloaded then parse it and then start the next activity :/

Answer (score 1):

Why use an activity at all? If all you are trying to do is show a busy indicator while downloading data you should use a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html). You can easily show the dialog with dialog.show() and close the dialog by calling dialog.dismiss(). If you want to set a custom message you can call dialog.setMessage("My Message").

Comment: Yeah, what bobbake said is good. You should also probably be aware of your activity's theme. Maybe try @android:style/Theme.Translucent